# Best practices for storing the metadata of publications in MySQL [PHP]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a website of publications with various types (Normal, Type 1, Type 2) and each type requires special data.

My question is:

What is the best way to store these "special data" in the database?

*1)* Create a table for each type of publication.
*2)* Create a table "posts_metadata" with the columns "post, key, value" and save all types in them.
*3)* create a "metadata" column in the "posts" table and save the "specials data" in them using JSON format.
*4)* create a "metadata" column in the "posts" table and save the "specials data" in them using XML format.

What do you think is the most efficient and practical option?

**Edit #1:**

Example of data:

Normal: `without "special data"`

Type 1:

```
'trademark' => 'Volkswagen'
'model' => 'gol 1.6'
'color' => 'white'
'doors' => '3'
'kms' => '17000'
..etc..
```

Type 2:

```
'color' => 'green'
'size' => '15x10'
'status' => 'new'
..etc..
```

...More Types...

Comment: gonna need some examples of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to query onto those special data fields choose option 2.

If you only want a storage for the data choose option 3. Depending on the possible size of the data I would create an extra table for it and depending on your version of mysql give the column the json-datatype, if you need the validation etc. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html.

Do not use option 4, in comparison to json xml creates too much overhead and adds no benefit in this scenario.

Comment: But, if I need store 10 "special data" I'll have to do 10 `INSERT` queries, is this a good practice?

Comment: It is normal practice. It will be good practice if you use [prepared statements] (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) for inserting the data, as the database will only have to parse the query one time and then you can simply execute the parsed query again with your other values. Another way would be to use a multi insert, you would just have to create a insert statement that looks like this `INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (1) (2)(3)`. The advantage of option 2 is the easiness of removing, updating and selecting those fields.

Comment: Using option 2, i have a problem with the update, if the key exists, I must update it, and if not exists I must insert it, but the problem is that i can't identify existing keys and i can't set 'meta_key' column as UNIQUE because it can be repeated in the others post rows...

Comment: A possible solution is remove all entries and then insert all new values, but this does not sound good.

Comment: You can set an unique index on the columns for the post_id and meta_key. `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX indexname ON posts_metadata (post_id, meta_key);`